# I want to find library to program augmented reality + GPS on IOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, gps, augmented-reality

I want to create some Android and iOS apps with augmented reality and GPS. This app should recognize big objects by camera (like a cars, buildings) and create some writings on this objects. We have all off recognizable objects GPS coordinate and photos of this place.
It app should work like - http://med44.com/v2/freshkills.php .

Id found some librarys:

artoolkit - free and have all instruments, but I think it will be difficult to program, and I will spend a lot of time by learning it

vuforia - in my opinion the best way to program this app, but havent work with GPS location. It is easyer than other

gimbal = vuforia + GPS, but it doesnt work in Russian Federation.

layar - I didnt understand what kind of AR task it can solve, but it looks like a Sass platform that you can add in you app. Looks great, but I dont know: can it solve my programming tasks?

arlab - there isnt any information about that. Is it lybrary can solve all of my tasks?

UPD: I found new lybrary - wikitube, but I dont know is that a good way to program my app with it?

And now Im thinking about: what library can I use for a recognition and show marks in real time on a IOS and Android?

Comment: Wikitude is good option for augment reality apps we can use gps and location awareness functionality with this sdk easily

Answer (score 0):

Use wikitude SDK, i recently implemented it in one of my apps and it works great for recognition using cloud and locally aswell. Attached is an example for how to user wikitude by code, you need to import their sdk before using the below code!

```
#define kWTLicenseKey @"put key here"

#import "WTSimpleClientTrackerViewController.h"

#import <WikitudeNativeSDK/WikitudeNativeSDK.h>

#import "StrokedRectangle.h"
#import "ExternalRenderer.h"
#import "ScanEvent.h"
#import "CokeStudioAPI.h"

@interface WTSimpleClientTrackerViewController () <WTWikitudeNativeSDKDelegate, WTClientTrackerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) WTWikitudeNativeSDK                           *wikitudeSDK;
@property (nonatomic, strong) WTClientTracker                               *clientTracker;

@property (nonatomic, strong) EAGLContext                                   *sharedWikitudeEAGLCameraContext;

@property (nonatomic, copy) WTWikitudeUpdateHandler                         wikitudeUpdateHandler;
@property (nonatomic, copy) WTWikitudeDrawHandler                           wikitudeDrawHandler;

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL                                          isTracking;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL                                          targetFound;
@property (nonatomic, strong) ExternalRenderer                              *renderer;
@property (nonatomic, strong) StrokedRectangle                              *renderableRectangle;

@end


@implementation WTSimpleClientTrackerViewController

#pragma mark UIViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.renderer = [[ExternalRenderer alloc] init];
    self.renderableRectangle = [[StrokedRectangle alloc] init];
    self.renderableRectangle.scale = 320.0f;

    self.wikitudeSDK = [[WTWikitudeNativeSDK alloc] initWithRenderingMode:WTRenderingMode_External delegate:self];
    [self.wikitudeSDK setLicenseKey:kWTLicenseKey];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didReceiveApplicationWillResignActiveNotification:) name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didReceiveApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification:) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = true;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didReceiveApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification:) name:kApplicationDidBecomeInActive object:nil];


}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear: animated];
    [[CokeStudioAPI sharedInstance] trackScreen:@"VR Camera"];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [self.renderer setupRenderingWithLayer:[self.eaglView eaglLayer]];
    [self.renderer startRenderLoopWithRenderBlock:[self renderBlock]];

    [self.wikitudeSDK start:nil completion:^(BOOL isRunning, NSError * __nonnull error) {
        if ( !isRunning ) {
            NSLog(@"Wikitude SDK is not running. Reason: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
        else
        {
            NSArray *paths = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask];
            NSURL *trackerURL = [[paths lastObject] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"tracker.wtc"];

            NSURL *clientTrackerURL = trackerURL;
            self.clientTracker = [self.wikitudeSDK.trackerManager create2DClientTrackerFromURL:clientTrackerURL extendedTargets:nil andDelegate:self];
        }
    }];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];

    [self.wikitudeSDK stop];

    [self.renderer stopRenderLoop];
    [self.renderer teardownRendering];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{
    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];

    [self.wikitudeSDK shouldTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


#pragma mark - ExternalRenderer render loop
- (ExternalRenderBlock)renderBlock
{
    return ^ (CADisplayLink *displayLink) {
        if ( self.wikitudeUpdateHandler
            &&
            self.wikitudeDrawHandler )
        {
            self.wikitudeUpdateHandler();
            self.wikitudeDrawHandler();
        }

        [self.renderer bindBuffer];

        if ( _isTracking )
        {
            [self.renderableRectangle drawInContext:[self.renderer internalContext]];
        }
    };
}

#pragma mark - Notifications
- (void)didReceiveApplicationWillResignActiveNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [self.wikitudeSDK stop];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion:nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [self.wikitudeSDK start:nil completion:^(BOOL isRunning, NSError * __nonnull error) {
        if ( !isRunning ) {
            NSLog(@"Wikitude SDK is not running. Reason: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }];
}

#pragma mark - Delegation
#pragma mark WTWikitudeNativeSDKDelegte
- (void)wikitudeNativeSDK:(WTWikitudeNativeSDK * __nonnull)wikitudeNativeSDK didCreatedExternalUpdateHandler:(WTWikitudeUpdateHandler __nonnull)updateHandler
{
    self.wikitudeUpdateHandler = updateHandler;
}

- (void)wikitudeNativeSDK:(WTWikitudeNativeSDK * __nonnull)wikitudeNativeSDK didCreatedExternalDrawHandler:(WTWikitudeDrawHandler __nonnull)drawHandler
{
    self.wikitudeDrawHandler = drawHandler;
}

- (EAGLContext *)eaglContextForVideoCameraInWikitudeNativeSDK:(WTWikitudeNativeSDK * __nonnull)wikitudeNativeSDK
{
    if (!_sharedWikitudeEAGLCameraContext )
    {
        EAGLContext *rendererContext = [self.renderer internalContext];
        self.sharedWikitudeEAGLCameraContext = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:[rendererContext API] sharegroup:[rendererContext sharegroup]];
    }
    return self.sharedWikitudeEAGLCameraContext;
}

- (CGRect)eaglViewSizeForExternalRenderingInWikitudeNativeSDK:(WTWikitudeNativeSDK * __nonnull)wikitudeNativeSDK
{
    return self.eaglView.bounds;
}

- (void)wikitudeNativeSDK:(WTWikitudeNativeSDK * __nonnull)wikitudeNativeSDK didEncounterInternalError:(NSError * __nonnull)error
{
}

#pragma mark WTClientTrackerDelegate

- (void)baseTracker:(nonnull WTBaseTracker *)baseTracker didRecognizedTarget:(nonnull WTImageTarget *)recognizedTarget
{

    _isTracking = YES;
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion:nil];

    NSDictionary* userInfo = @{@"artistName": [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[recognizedTarget name]]};
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"targetFound" object:self userInfo:userInfo];

}

- (void)baseTracker:(nonnull WTBaseTracker *)baseTracker didTrackTarget:(nonnull WTImageTarget *)trackedTarget
{
    [self.renderableRectangle setProjectionMatrix:trackedTarget.projection];
    [self.renderableRectangle setModelViewMatrix:trackedTarget.modelView];
}

- (void)baseTracker:(nonnull WTBaseTracker *)baseTracker didLostTarget:(nonnull WTImageTarget *)lostTarget
{
    _isTracking = NO;
}

- (IBAction)doneBtnTapped:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion:nil];
}

- (void)clientTracker:(nonnull WTClientTracker *)clientTracker didFinishedLoadingTargetCollectionFromURL:(nonnull NSURL *)URL
{
}

- (void)clientTracker:(nonnull WTClientTracker *)clientTracker didFailToLoadTargetCollectionFromURL:(nonnull NSURL *)URL withError:(nonnull NSError *)error
{
}
```